# Change default selection in edit rejection dialogue box from "copied content" to "invalid edit"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, suggested-edits

Having had access to the pending edit queue for a full two days now, it appears that very few proposed edits are rejected due to content being plagiarized from another source without attribution. Most are rejected due to the editor attempting to add what should be a comment, or because their change was too significant.

With that in mind, **could the default selection be changed from "copied content" to "invalid edit"?** This is a minor thing, but selecting those minuscule boxes is a pain in the buttocks. I supposed a larger feature request could be to enable the radio buttons to be chosen via keyboard (<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> or something), but that can be a separate feature request.

Just in case it's needed, this is currently the default:

[image: default rejection dialog box]

Comment: Definitely.  Copied content is easily the rarest form of crap post in my experience.

Comment: @MatthewRead Copied content is pretty common for tag wikis and just about irrelevant (shouldn't be in the list) for questions and answers.

Comment: @Gilles no real point removing it imho, in light of my change. It is still a valid reason for rejecting in very rare cases.

Comment: [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let me make an interesting observation first though:

If I change this so the "most common" rejection reason is selected first, users will tend to go with the default, as opposed to think about the real reason for rejection.

For example, take these rejections:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/128277 and
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/128274

It is clear to me that Andrew rejected these edits with an invalid reason. If we default to something else we are just going to have different invalid reasons.

So:

[image: think]

You can no longer even submit the rejection without explicitly selecting a box. I want us to have valid reasons for rejections.

So ... to recap ... **NO** I will not be changing the default, instead I am eliminating a default selection.

Comment: Custom rejection reason, when'd that happen?

Comment: now ... I just added it

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: +1 for the "custom"; I was going to make a second post about the fact that none of the choices are appropriate for tag edits, which uses the same form, but the "custom" kindasorta fixes that.

Comment: I got all excited about this, but when I checked I'm still seeing the old list of options; do I just need to be more patient?

Comment: @joran yes ... we will deploy soon

Answer (score 2):

If we're going to have *no* selection by default, then please modify it so the five (now six) appear in the page tab order. Currently, when the "why are you rejecting?" box is open, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> sends the selection to the "search" box on the top right of the page. Opening the rejection box should make:

1. the six radio buttons first on tab order
2. the "other" box seventh on tab order
3. the the "reject" button eighth
4. the "cancel" text ninth

This should speed up the response selection time for us keyboard jockeys.

Comment: I don't know how it works on other platforms, but on a Mac radio buttons are given the same tab position and you use the arrow keys to change the selection. If it doesn't work the same, then this might make it more difficult to do this.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw - If that's how it works, then that's what I meant; I haven't played around with tab orders in a while and probably just got it wrong.