# My edit was rejected for incorrect (and seemingly random) reasons. How do I justify and resubmit it without starting a little edit fight?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently submitted [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/128277). It makes some small but obvious improvements to the question:

- The title "SQL Server Service Broker" is not a question and gives no clue as to *what* you're asking about Service Broker. I edited the title to basically repeat the question in the body.
- The question is not about SQL (no code, queries, etc.) so I removed that tag. The question is specific to SQL Server 2008 so I added that tag.

I guess these simple improvements were not as obvious as I thought they were because they were summarily rejected by two reviewers who gave [the following reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/128277):

> **[eykanal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168775/eykanal) said:** This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
>
> **[Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111124/andrew) said:** This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution.

*What?*

- How do I talk to these reviewers to understand their reasoning?  Should I even bother?
- What controls the quality of a reviewer's decisions?
- How do I resubmit my edit without triggering a little edit fight? (Or is my edit really that bad?)

Comment: OK, I just did the edit, taken care of. (and cast a close vote).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just resubmit it.  While the question should be closed as 'Not Constructive', your edit looked just fine.  Who knows why they rejected it, especially the plagiarize reason, but everyone makes mistakes on those.

Comment: I think plagiarized gets picked frequently because it's the default and people are too lazy to go through the list looking for a real reason

Comment: The plagiarize reason is checked by default, strangely, so in practice it's the didn't-pick-a-reason reason. This has already been [noted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections/107930#comment278155_107930) and [formally requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110277).

Comment: @Giles - Amusingly, the OP on that request is one of the rejectors here.

Comment: @ire_and_curses not amusing, that is clear abuse.

Comment: @waffles - not sure I understand. Can you expand the context? Who is abusing who?

Comment: @ire - I think he's suggesting that since the rejector is clearly *aware* of the problem, he's actively abusing the system by refusing to pick an appropriate reason.

Comment: @ire_and_curses what shog said

Comment: @waffles The guy who made that feature request chose invalid edit though, not copied content.

Answer (score 8):

This happened due to a bug of mine. Hopefully the change I am just about to deploy will make sure it does not happen in future.

[Change default selection in edit rejection dialogue box from "copied content" to "invalid edit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110277/change-default-selection-in-edit-rejection-dialogue-box-from-copied-content-to/110811#110811)

I agree the specific edit should be rejected:

- The word "cool" in the title is really not needed.
- Closed questions really do not need to be bumped, there is little value in improving it.

Comment: The question was closed after I asked about it here. :) And yes, the word is cool is not needed, but rest of edit to the title gave it some more value (where it had little before).

Comment: @Nick fair enough don't dwell on it, the big reason for this mistake was just fixed. In general question asking for shopping lists should be avoided.

Comment: I agree, the Service Broker question was ultimately inappropriate for SO.  My question here about reviewer actions is independent of that, though. Anyway, thank you for tweaking the relevant UX. And [nice freehand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110277/change-default-selection-in-edit-rejection-dialogue-box-from-copied-content-to/110811#110811). Heh.

Answer (score 0):

Question is too old for such edit to really matter. No need to bump it to the front.

There is no "question too old" reason so they just chose in random, the "plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution" is simply the first and default reason.

Comment: That seems like an odd default reason.

Comment: So you say, but it's pretty annoying when searching for a solution to something and you get a bunch of results that have non-descriptive titles or are mistagged.

Comment: I'm with @Troyen. I edited the post simply to improve it, not to bump it to the front page. (Given that the question, ultimately, is not appropriate for SO, is beside the point.) I came across it in the "Related" sidebar and found the title to be utterly useless.

Comment: Would an "edit-but-don't-bump" feature be reasonable and/or feasible?

Comment: @KeithThompson [No](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers)

Comment: @Troyen sometimes it's true, but personally I don't think it's true in case of that question. It can always be edited with 2K+ member who think it should be changed, I won't start Rollback fight over this just won't approve such suggestion.